# Set Column Value of Pandas Dataframe Based on Variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    col1   col2
0    a      7                    
1    b      3                  
2    c      1                  
3    d      6
```

I'm trying to add a new column to the dataframe, with the value equal to a variable `x`. This variable will depend on the values of `col1` and `col2`. I have tried:

```
for row in df:
    row['col3'] = x
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I had a look into 
[`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) however I'm not sure this is the right approach. According to the documentation:

> "You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect."

**Edit - Additional Info:**

What I'm trying to do is create a new dataframe with `col3` being a string based on a pre-sorted order of the dataframe. For example, the following dataframe:

```
    col1   col2
0    a      7                    
1    b      3                  
2    c      1                  
3    d      6
```

Should become:

```
    col1   col2   col 3 
0    a      7      001              
1    b      3      002            
2    c      1      003            
3    d      6      004
```

Where `col3` is a string in the format '000' (i.e. with leading zeros where applicable so that the string always contains 3 characters). There will never be more than 999 rows in the dataframe.

This is the code I have so far:

```
x = 1

for row in df:

    if x < 10:
        formatting = str('00' + str(x))
    elif x < 100:
        formatting = str('0' + str(x))
    else:
        formatting = str(str(x))

    x += 1

    row['col3'] = x
```

However this seems to change the `col3` values for **all** rows in the dataframe, intsead of just the row in the loop. For example after 4 loops the result is:

```
    col1   col2   col 3 
0    a      7      004              
1    b      3      004            
2    c      1      004            
3    d      6      004
```

Comment: In what way does `x` depend on `col1` and `col2`?

Comment: You can apply a function to a dataframe using apply.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: what is x here?

Comment: Can you check edited answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Better here is use [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) with index values converted to strings:

```
df['col3'] = (df.index + 1).astype('str').str.zfill(3)
print (df)
  col1  col2 col3
0    a     7  001
1    b     3  002
2    c     1  003
3    d     6  004
```

If index is not default RangeIndex create helper `Series`:

```
df['col3'] = pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)).astype('str').str.zfill(3)
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. I tried this and it sucessfully creates `col3` with string value equal to the index + 1. However since the dataframe will be sorted, the index will not always start at zero, causing `col3` to be based on the original index rather than the new order after sorting. Do I need to reset the index after sorting?

Comment: @Alan - If not default index, use second solution.

Comment: Or exacly `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` and first solution.

Comment: Thank you :) I'd never previously used `zfill` - this will be a huge time saver.